# GXT 3.0.6 and GWT 2.5.1 Binding not update data in model

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am not able to retrieve data from FramedPanel using Bindings and BaseModelData with 2 fields. Can anyone tell me what went wrong..
I have also tried with and Editor options but it doesn't bind the data at all to the UI..

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    BaseModelData baseModelData;
    FramedPanel formPanel;
    Bindings bindings;
    User user = new User();
public Widget getLoginForm(){
          TextField textField = new TextField();
          textField.setHeight(10);
          textField.addValidator(new EmptyValidator<String>());
          textField.setName("userId");

          PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
          passwordField.setName("password");
          VBoxLayoutContainer boxLayoutContainer = new VBoxLayoutContainer(VBoxLayoutAlign.CENTER);

          boxLayoutContainer.add(new FieldLabel(textField,"User Id"));
          boxLayoutContainer.add(new FieldLabel(passwordField, "Password"));
          map.put("userId", "asd");
          map.put("password", "");

          formPanel = new FramedPanel();
          formPanel.add(boxLayoutContainer);

           bindings = new Bindings();
          bindings.addFieldBinding(new FieldBinding(textField,"userId"));
          bindings.addFieldBinding(new FieldBinding(passwordField,"password"));

          baseModelData = new BaseModelData();
          baseModelData.setProperties(map);

          bindings.bind(baseModelData);

          TextButton b = new TextButton("Login");
          b.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
            Info.display("User Id : ", baseModelData.get("password").toString());

            }
        });
          formPanel.addButton(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the GWT editor framework for data binding.

Take a look at this documentation from Sencha:

http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/data/editors/Editors.html

Using the Bindings and BaseModelData class is old styled GXT. It is part from the legacy package and should help to migrate an existing project. If you start a new project with GXT 3, I suggest to use the GWT editor framework.

Comment: I have also tried the Editor option but there is no luck... Can you suggest me what could be the problem with editor framework also.. The data not even bind and appear on UI. Id you have any example please share with me..

Comment: I can confirm, that the editor framework  works really nice with GXT 3. Have yu looked at the link? There is all you need to get the editor framework to work.

Comment: Thank you It is working now.. With some configuration related to @Path it works..